# Calculating average value into new field using layer file?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, layer-file

I have a layer file with a BE field. Some BE have more than one BU. Each BU has a scorecard number.  I need to calculate the average of those scores per BE.  I need this in the layer file to be able to symbolize the data.

I copy a  clip from the table

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the Summary Statistics tool in the Analysis>Statistics toolbox, there is an option to specify a case field, BE, when you calculate a statistic (specify "mean" as Statistic Type) on another field, Scorecard.  The output is a table which you can then join to your original attribute table.
[image]

Comment: I was hoping to get a python script that can do the calculation in the layer file but this is also an avenue.  However I get this  error when populating the Statistics Field:  "Error 000800  The value is not a member of SUM|MEAN|NIN|MAX|RANGE|STD|.  I get the same error if i try other numeric fields with field properties of double or short

Comment: You can easily make it a python script.  It's just an arcpy command:  Statistics_analysis (in_table, out_table, statistics_fields, {case_field}).

Comment: As for your error, you are using the pull-down options under Statistics Type? (See updated graphic in answer.)

Comment: Sorry my mistake which i noticed and corrected.  I get results but it appears that the tool returns the max value, not the mean even though I ensured that i use the mean option.

Comment: If you choose "MAX" you will get the max value.  If you choose 'MEAN' you will get the mean.